# Is it possible to render a VRM model in python using the MToon shader?

Tags: python, gltf, fbx, 3d-modelling

I am using Python 3.9.
I have two files, a VRM model and an FBX animation. I want to animate the VRM model using the FBX animation in Python so that I can both display a preview in a GUI and stream the results to a virtual camera using `pyvirtualcam`.

I have tried using the library Pyrender but since VRMs have extra important information (like the MToon Shader) it has either produced a render with holes in the textures and geometery.
I have found that Pixiv has an official expansion for Three.js but since my project is in Python that doesn't quite seem to work for me. That sucks considering it seems to manage the rendering perfectly.
There is also a library for Swift but again, it's not Python.
I have also managed to extract the extra data from the model using `pygltflib` but I lack the knowledge to do anything with it.

I am very inexperienced with 3D rendering so I apologise in advance. Any knowledge or ideas about how I could achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: would you consider using blender?

Comment: What do you mean? In what way?

Comment: Blender has a python API and you can import VRM and FBX animation ...

Comment: I suppose that could work, although from what I've read it seems like I'd have to rebuild blender as a python 3.9 package. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: If it's possible, adapting to blender's python version could be a practical solution

Comment: Maybe, although since I primarily use Python 3.9 for my projects it might be my best bet.